# Any resources out there for color blind web designers?

Tags: colors, color-blindness

My 9-5 job is as a software engineer so this usually isn't a problem for me, but I do know HTML and css and feel like I can come up with a decent layout if needed...

The only problem is when it comes to selecting a color scheme for sites.  Usually I will just find a site that has colors that I think look nice and most likely aren't weird (ie [George W. Bush's](http://www.georgewbushcenter.com/) website isn't likely to have pinks and purples in it).  Once I have found a site with good colors I can use that as a base.  It would be nice to find a place that has a "safe" color pallet to choose from or gave you a list of "safe" colors that complement each other.

I'm not *exactly* sure what "safe" colors are.  I suppose in my situation I am trying to stay away from pinks and purples which I often confuse with more conservative colors (greys and blues respectively).  In addition to that, I'd like to know that the colors are aesthetically pleasing.

Does anyone know of anything out there where I can find a hex codes for "safe" colors and any colors that would compliment my base color?

When I say hex codes for safe colors I'm not looking for the answer: "Grey's hex code is #808080"

In my experience there is a wide range of grey and it would be nice to get that hex range...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I honestly can't think of anything off the top of my head, but I can imagine that it would be very helpful for plenty of others.

Comment: The answer might well help those of us with simply no *taste* wrt colours as well :)

Comment: What do you mean by safe?  Do you mean visible by those who are color blind, or do you mean aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what "safe" colors are. I suppose in my situation I am trying to stay away from pinks and purples which I often confuse with more conservative colors (greys and blues respectively).  In addition to that I guess I am looking for colors that compliment each other.  AKA 'aesthetically pleasing'.  FYI it's not that color blind people don't see certain colors, they just mix them up with others.

Comment: Is there no one with good colour taste that you can ask?

Comment: Usually there is. That doesn't mean I like it and it doesn't mean they are always willing and able to answer my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always liked [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com), which is put together by Adobe.

There are some nice tools on the site for finding complementary colors and creating schemes from individual colors or uploaded images, but you can also just choose from among many user-generated and voted-upon "themes," complete with all the RGB, CMYK, HSL, hex, etc. you'd ever want.

Answer (score 0):

iphone app - ColorPixel 1.2.1 - identify colors using your camera in real-time